# Reflection page using xcoffins

Tags: positioning, geometry, xcoffins

I am missing something when it comes to creating a page that mirrors this page (reflect this page over the y-axis/vertical fold)

[image: Fool page 1]

[image: Fool page 2]

Here is my xcoffins code:

```
%\documentclass[10pt]{article}   
\documentclass[class=article, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor, fontspec}
 \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\setmainfont{Futura}

\usepackage{ifthen,changepage} % check odd or even page

\usepackage[papersize={7.5in,7.5in}, top=1in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%  shipout even and odd pages title and figures
            \checkoddpage
\checkoddpage
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{oddpage}}{\TypesetCoffin\FrameOFoxx}{\TypesetCoffin\FrameEFoxx}}
    }

\NewCoffin\FrameOFoxx
\NewCoffin\FrameOddFoxx
\NewCoffin\FigFoxTT
\NewCoffin\FigFoxBT
\NewCoffin\FigFoxRT
\NewCoffin\FigFoxRM
\NewCoffin\FigFoxLB
\NewCoffin\FigFoxM
\NewCoffin\FigFoxRTM
\NewCoffin\FigFoxRTL

\NewCoffin\FrameEFoxx
\NewCoffin\FrameEvenFoxx

%%%%%%%%%   set figures width/height  plus height of text area
\newlength{\imageFoxRT}
\setlength{\imageFoxRT}{0.75in} % height and width of the figures
\newlength{\imageFoxRM}
\setlength{\imageFoxRM}{1.0175in}
\newlength{\imageFoxLB}
\setlength{\imageFoxLB}{2in}
\newlength{\textstyFox}
\setlength{\textstyFox}{2.9in}

\newlength{\textHFox}
\setlength{\textHFox}{6in} % <<<<<<<<<<<<
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    
\SetVerticalCoffin\FrameOddFoxx{\textHFox}{\color{white}\rule{\textHFox}{\textHFox}}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigFoxRT{\imageFoxRT}{%bottom image
    \includegraphics[height=1in,width=1.368in]{00eyeofthoth}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigFoxRTM{\imageFoxRT}{% top left
    \includegraphics[height=\imageFoxRT,width=\imageFoxRT]{Gseedoflife}
    \begin{center}
        \scriptsize{AETHER}
    \end{center}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigFoxRTL{\imageFoxRT}{%top right
    \includegraphics[height=\imageFoxRT,width=0.387\imageFoxRT]{00L}
    \begin{center}  
        \hspace*{-0.45in}\scriptsize{LORD}
    \end{center}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigFoxLB{\imageFoxLB}{% topmost
    \includegraphics[height=\imageFoxLB, width=\imageFoxLB]{fox}
\begin{center}
    \textit{The mask, the divine; \\ All things, in their time.}
\end{center}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigFoxTT{\textstyFox}{
{\huge 00. The Fox}

\vspace{0.25cm}

{\scriptsize\textbf{Mercenarium Function:} 00. The Fox is summoned into play as a Lord with no suit. When summoned, roll the Fox die and place it on the card. The number rolled sets the card’s suit and special effect; if set to 1, 2, 3 or 4, the card functions as a Lord of Claws, Souls, Gears or Blades, respectively. If set to 5, the card functions as the Lord of Stars, which causes silence and prevents all players from singing hymns until the Fox die has changed or 00. The Fox has been removed from play. If set to the Seed of Life icon, the card functions as the Lord of Flowers, and can be used by its owner as a base to field summon any card of any face value. The player that controls 00. The Fox may use their turn action to re-roll the Fox die.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\scriptsize If 00. The Fox is moved by the effects of III. Optimo, IX. The Shade, or XI. Visionaire, its die value remains the same as before it was moved.}

\vspace{0.15cm}
\rule{2.9in}{0.1pt}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\scriptsize\textbf{Dragonfruit Meanings:}
\textbf{Laughter} / Understanding, Ease, Serenity}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\scriptsize The Fox represents the energy of divine creation, and those flashes where we realize the beauty of the universe and bring our awareness to the present. It embodies the mantra of “be here now”, the experience of satori, and is a salve for the painful lessons of life, giving them meaning through context in the eternal unfolding of reality. It hearkens to those moments of childlike bliss in which we are delighted to simply experience things, unconcerned with the past, the future, our projects, and obligations. There is an elusive state of mind brought about by peaceful awareness, in which egoistic pursuit gives way to a formless and light sensation, and through which all great and powerful works become something that feels almost effortless to complete – flow. It is this state of mind that The Fox seeks to emphasize. Its intimate relationship with The Fool, and its connection through alteration, \\ represents the lurking fears that can so easily plunge us out of flow and back into foolishness, as we twist and turn through lessons and laughter, ignorance and bliss, in the eternal dance of existence.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\scriptsize The Fool thinks it’s good to be The Fox; but The Fox knows itself to be The Fool} 
}

%********************************************* set & assembly the content of even and odd pages 
\newlength{\HoffsetFox}
\setlength{\HoffsetFox}{\oddsidemargin}

% *************** even pages 
\JoinCoffins*\FrameEvenFoxx[l,b]\FigFoxRTL[l,b](0in,0in)% top right
\JoinCoffins*\FrameEvenFoxx[l,b]\FigFoxRTM[l,b](0in,0in)
\JoinCoffins*\FrameEvenFoxx[l,b]\FigFoxRT[l,b](0in,0in)
\JoinCoffins*\FrameEvenFoxx[r,t]\FigFoxTT[r,t](0in,0pt)% top text
\JoinCoffins*\FrameEvenFoxx[l,t]\FigFoxLB[l,t](0in,0in) %bottom image

\JoinCoffins*\FrameEFoxx[r,t]\FrameEvenFoxx[r,t]

% *************** odd pages
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOFoxx[hc,vc]\FrameOddFoxx[l,t](\HoffsetFox,-\baselineskip) 
%*********************************************  

\clearpage 

\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}

    \textit{{\large 1 confession}}\\
    \textit{{\large 1nce a myth's erased}}\\
    \textit{{\large 2$^{nd}$ lesson lost without a}}\\
    \textit{{\large Tr\'{e}s}}\\
    
\end{center}
\vfill
\clearpage

\pagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

All images are the same sizes. I cannot figure out what is wrong in my JoinCoffins. When I build the file, everything is stacked in the top left corner of the page instead of where I want it to be. I know to reposition from the poles using the ordered pairs at the end of JoinCoffins, but I cannot get my text to be on the right side. Any help is welcomed!

Comment: I did not read the question because I could not stop looking at the beautiful screenshot.

Comment: Thank you! This belongs to a project I am working on typesetting for someone. I am not responsible for the gorgeous artwork. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** Is this what you want?  (pages also reversed)

I just made a small changes in the `Join`s to reverse the positions of the images and the text. I also included the text of the first page into a `xcoffin` to simplify the code.

(I do not have the Futura font installed, so I commented that line)

[image: yyy]

```
%\documentclass[10pt]{article}   
\documentclass[class=article, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
 %\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor, fontspec}
 \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
%\setmainfont{Futura}

\usepackage{ifthen,changepage} % check odd or even page

\usepackage[papersize={7.5in,7.5in}, top=0.75in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in, bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%  shipout even and odd pages title and figures
            \checkoddpage
\checkoddpage
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{oddpage}}{\TypesetCoffin\FrameEFoxx}{\TypesetCoffin\FrameOFoxx}} % reverse also the pages
    }

\NewCoffin\FrameOFoxx
\NewCoffin\FrameOddFoxx
\NewCoffin\FigFoxTT
\NewCoffin\FigFoxBT
\NewCoffin\FigFoxRT
\NewCoffin\FigFoxRM
\NewCoffin\FigFoxLB
\NewCoffin\FigFoxM
\NewCoffin\FigFoxRTM
\NewCoffin\FigFoxRTL

\NewCoffin\FrameEFoxx
\NewCoffin\FrameEvenFoxx
\NewCoffin\TextEvenFoxx

%%%%%%%%%   set figures width/height  plus height of text area
\newlength{\imageFoxRT}
\setlength{\imageFoxRT}{0.75in} % height and width of the figures
\newlength{\imageFoxRM}
\setlength{\imageFoxRM}{1.0175in}
\newlength{\imageFoxLB}
\setlength{\imageFoxLB}{2in}
\newlength{\textstyFox}
\setlength{\textstyFox}{2.9in}

\newlength{\textHFox}
\setlength{\textHFox}{6in} % 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
 \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
 \pagestyle{empty}
 
 % ********* filling the boxes      
\SetVerticalCoffin\FrameOddFoxx{\textHFox}{\color{white}\rule{\textHFox}{\textHFox}} %frame collector 
\SetVerticalCoffin\FrameEvenFoxx{\textHFox}{\color{white}\rule{\textHFox}{\textHFox}} %frame collector

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigFoxRT{1.368in}{%bottom image
    \includegraphics[height=1in,width=1.368in]{example-image-c}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigFoxRTM{\imageFoxRT}{%center left 2
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=\imageFoxRT,width=\imageFoxRT]{example-image-b}
    
    \scriptsize{VOID}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigFoxRTL{0.387\imageFoxRT}{%center left 1
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=\imageFoxRT,width=0.387\imageFoxRT]{example-image-a}
    
    \scriptsize{LORD}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigFoxLB{\imageFoxLB}{% topmost left
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=\imageFoxLB, width=\imageFoxLB]{example-grid-100x100pt}%
    
    \textit{Many masks, No mind.}
}
    
\SetVerticalCoffin\FigFoxTT{\textstyFox}{%
{\huge 00. The Fox}

\vspace{0.25cm}

{\scriptsize\textbf{Mercenarium Function:} 00. The Fox is summoned into play as a Lord with no suit. When summoned, roll the Fox die and place it on the card. The number rolled sets the card’s suit and special effect; if set to 1, 2, 3 or 4, the card functions as a Lord of Claws, Souls, Gears or Blades, respectively. If set to 5, the card functions as the Lord of Stars, which causes silence and prevents all players from singing hymns until the Fox die has changed or 00. The Fox has been removed from play. If set to the Seed of Life icon, the card functions as the Lord of Flowers, and can be used by its owner as a base to field summon any card of any face value. The player that controls 00. The Fox may use their turn action to re-roll the Fox die.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\scriptsize If 00. The Fox is moved by the effects of III. Optimo, IX. The Shade, or XI. Visionaire, its die value remains the same as before it was moved.}

\vspace{0.15cm}
\rule{2.9in}{0.1pt}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\scriptsize\textbf{Dragonfruit Meanings:}
\textbf{Laughter} / Understanding, Ease, Serenity}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\scriptsize The Fox represents the energy of divine creation, and those flashes where we realize the beauty of the universe and bring our awareness to the present. It embodies the mantra of “be here now”, the experience of satori, and is a salve for the painful lessons of life, giving them meaning through context in the eternal unfolding of reality. It hearkens to those moments of childlike bliss in which we are delighted to simply experience things, unconcerned with the past, the future, our projects, and obligations. }

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\scriptsize The Fool thinks it’s good to be The Fox; but The Fox knows itself to be The Fool.} 
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\TextEvenFoxx{\textstyFox}{%
\centering  \large
\textit{1 confession\\
 1nce a myth's erased\\
2$^{nd}$ lesson lost without a\\
 Tr\'{e}s}
}   

%********************************************* set & assembly the content of even and odd pages 
\newlength{\HoffsetFox}
\setlength{\HoffsetFox}{\oddsidemargin}

% *************** now on even page, reversed by atbegshi    
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddFoxx[l,t]\FigFoxLB[l,t](0in,0in) %top left
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddFoxx[l,t]\FigFoxRTL[l,vc](0in,-1.5\imageFoxLB-1.368in/2)%  left center 1  
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddFoxx[l,t]\FigFoxRTM[l,vc](\imageFoxLB-\imageFoxRT,-1.5\imageFoxLB-1.368in/2)%  left center 2
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddFoxx[l,b]\FigFoxRT[l,b](\imageFoxLB/2-1.368in/2,0in) % bottom figure
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddFoxx[r,t]\FigFoxTT[r,t](0in,0in)  % text column  right

\JoinCoffins*\FrameOFoxx[l,t]\FrameOddFoxx[l,t](\HoffsetFox,-\HoffsetFox)   

%********************************************* now on odd page,  reversed by atbegshi
\JoinCoffins*\FrameEvenFoxx[hc,vc]\TextEvenFoxx[hc,vc](0in,0in) % text centered on first page

\JoinCoffins*\FrameEFoxx[l,t]\FrameEvenFoxx[l,t](\HoffsetFox,-\HoffsetFox) 
%% *******************************************************************************
% first page blank
\mbox{} 
\clearpage
% new blank, second page
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}  

\end{document}
```

I more or less guessed the alignment of the figures. If you want something like this

[image: cr]

Change the line

```
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddFoxx[l,t]\FigFoxRTL[l,vc](0in,-1.5\imageFoxLB-1.368in/2)%  left center 1
```

for

```
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddFoxx[l,t]\FigFoxRTL[l,vc](\imageFoxLB/2-1.368in/2,-1.5\imageFoxLB-1.368in/2)%  left center 1
```

to align the left borders of `A` and `C`.

Comment: this is what I was thinking. The only change that I need to make now is for the pages to be reversed. That is the small text on the odd page and the big text and images on the even page. An end to reflect the beginning.

Comment: Thank for your feedback. I changed the answer following your suggestions. Good luck with your project! :-)

Comment: This is precisely what I was trying to do. You are the best!